# How to combine two multi-column dynamic arrays to make one dynamic array in a formula?

Tags: excel, excel-365

I have two 2D ranges both dynamic arrays. I understand I can use CHOOSE function to stack columns side by side or stack row below row easily. However, this fails when two things being stacked have more than one rows or columns.
How do I append/stack two dynamic arrays in a formula where each of those dynamic arrays have multiple rows.

Example:

```
Cell A1 = UNIQUE(rng1) --> resulting in 4 cells - A1:B2
Cell C1 = UNIQUE(rng2) --> resulting in 4 cells - C1:D2
```

I want to stack both and get a dynamic result, in this case A1:D2

How do I do this combination?

`=CHOOSE({1;2},A1#,C1#)` doesn't work, it seems to pick up first row of both dynamic arrays.

Comment: One way is described [here](https://exceljet.net/formula/combine-ranges) or using Lambda [here](https://exceljet.net/formula/lambda-append-range)

Comment: Thanks, I will try the first one. I don't yet have LAMBDA available.